# AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' Дополнение модели User

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Привет, объясните, почему возникает ошибка.

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Sergey/Documents/mysite/django.testsite/testsite/login/views.py", line 38, in register
    newuser_form = SignUpForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 91, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 291, in __init__
    object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 82, in model_to_dict
    opts = instance._meta
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 216, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

views

```
def register(request):
args = {}
args['forms'] = SignUpForm()
args['form1'] = ImagefieldForm()
if request.POST:
    newuser_form = SignUpForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
    image_field_form = ImagefieldForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
    if newuser_form.is_valid() and image_field_form.is_valid():
        user = newuser_form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        print ('User saved')
        image_field_form.save()
        #userfield = request.POST.get('username', '')
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        mail_subject = 'Welcome to site'
        message = render_to_string('login_app/please_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = newuser_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
        email.send()
        return HttpResponse('Please check your email')

    else:
        args['forms'] = newuser_form
return render(request, 'login_app/registration.html', args)
```

models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/users', blank=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created:
       Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
   instance.profile.save()
```

forms

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, help_text='Please enter your email', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'example@gmail.com'}), validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}', message='Incorrect email')])
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[a-z]', message='Incorrect name')])

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

class ImagefieldForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('avatar', )
```

Answer (score 1):

Делайте проверку

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
```

перед вашим кодом

```
newuser_form = SignUpForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
```